# GWT: Safe place for properties file with db variables

Tags: gwt, properties, server-side

I have a file ***variables.properties*** in my GWT application inside the ***war folder***. The file contains a jdbc string, username and password, hence I would not like to see it on the client side in any way.

**My question**: Is *variables.properties* somehow integrated into client side code at runtime when placed inside the *war folder* or is it safe to place it there?

If it is not, where should I put it?
I read the file with this code:

```
variables = new Properties();
BufferedInputStream stream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("variables.properties"));
variables.load(stream);
stream.close();
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could take a look at `Constants`, but I'm not sure it complains with all your security needs. http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.4/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/Constants.html

Comment: Thank you for the hint, I will take a look immediately!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want the properties to be visible to the GWT client code (or to a web browser poking around) you can load them from your classpath. That way they'll end up in `WEB-INF/classes` which is not visible. If you're using Maven you can store your properties files in `src/main/resources`. Otherwise you can store them next to your Java source files and make sure they get copied during your build process. You can load them from the classpath by using: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)

Comment: That works, thank you!
I moved variables.properties to the server package and do the following:

    BufferedInputStream stream = new BufferedInputStream(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("variables.properties"));